# How to check if a session in JFactory::getSession() is set or not ?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have the following lines in joomla 2.5 `viewform.php` in view of a component

```
 $session = & JFactory::getSession();
 if(empty($session->get('MasterIndex'))) $session->set('MasterIndex',0);
```

and I get

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
>   /var/www/ ..

I also tried

```
 if(empty($session->get('MasterIndex'))) $session->set('MasterIndex',0);
```

How can i check if the session value is set or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$setSession = $session->get('MasterIndex');
if(empty($setSession)) $session->set('MasterIndex',0);
```

Note: You are getting that error because [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error

Answer (score 1):

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$setSession = $session->get('MasterIndex');
if(empty($setSession)) 
{
    $s_var = $session->set('MasterIndex',0);
}
else
{
    $s_var = $session->set('MasterIndex',1);
}

echo $s_var;
```

Try this.....

Comment: thank you, as @Sudhir mention, it's about empty, I can't use it directly on $sesion->get because it returns a value and its not a variable. So your code will work. Thanx